# How to reload linked libraries from script?

Tags: scripting, linked-data, outliner

As far as I know there are two ways to reload a linked library (so the linked objects update to the state they are in the source file) in `Blender 2.8`:

1. **Close and reopen** the file with the linked library.
2. **Reload button** inside the `Outliner > Blender File > RMB (over the linked linked .blend file) > Reload`.

The reload button seems to call an `Outliner` operation: `bpy.ops.outliner.lib_operation(type='RELOAD')`. But I think is not a good idea to call `bpy.ops.outliner` from a script *(neither I can find a way to do it)*. I think must exist some other call over `bpy.data` to to the same thing (and safer than call a `operator`), but I cannot find it.

Is there a way to reload the linked library from a script? If the only way is calling the above mentioned "outliner operation", how can I call it from a script?

> I'd like to iterate over all linked libraries and update them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the data of the blend file

```
bpy.data.libraries[YOUR BLENDER FILE NAME HERE].reload()
```